# Why is this function holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

consider a locally integrable function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and then the function $\phi(z):= \int\limits_{1/n}^n t^{z-1}\cdot f(t) dt$ for some fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I'm wondering why this function is holomorphic?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First show that $\phi$ is continuous. Then integrate $\phi$ around a simple closed curve $\gamma$ and use Fubini's theorem:
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \phi(z)\,dz &= \int_{\gamma} \left( \int_{1/n}^n t^{z-1} f(t)\,dt \right)\,dz \\
&= \int_{1/n}^n \left( \int_{\gamma} t^{z-1} \,dz \right) f(t)\,dt = 0
\end{align}
by Cauchy's integral theorem since $z \mapsto t^{z-1}$ is holomorphic for each $t \in [1/n,n]$.

By Morera's theorem, $\phi$ is holomorphic.